# Replace string in multiple lines having new line and tabs

Tags: javascript, regex

This is the original code,

```
<View style={[styles.container, { width, height }]}>
  <View style={[styles.imageContainer, imageContainerStyles]}>{image}</View>
  {titleElement}
  {subtitleElement}
</View>
```

That I want to look like this using javascript replace(),

```
<View style={[styles.container, { width, height }]}>
  <View>{image}</View>
</View>
```

Basically, I just want to remove the {titleElement} & {subtitleElement} and keep the image without the style.

Since those have new lines and indented with tabs, I tried doing this,

```
const result = data.replace(/<View style={\[styles\.imageContainer, 
      imageContainerStyles]}>{image}<\/View>\n\t{titleElement}\n\t{subtitleElement}/g, 
  '<View>{image}</View>');
```

But it's not working. It's my first time working with regex and I'm stuck.

Comment: You might want to consider parsing your text as HTML/XML and then using JavaScript's capabilities to do these replacements.

Answer (score 0):

I rewote your regex, basically I made more escaping and changed your '`Newlines`' and '`tabs`' to `'\s*?'`. That will match any number of `White Space` characters.

Now it Works with your replacement. Here's the regex:

```
/\<View style=\{\[styles\.imageContainer,\s*?imageContainerStyles\]\}\>\{image\}\<\/View>\s*?\{titleElement\}\s*?\{subtitleElement\}/
```

Just use your replacement string as is.